# Displacement relation of a progresive wave

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, oscillators, displacement

I know that the displacement relation of a body in simple harmonic motion (SHM) is given by

$$x(t) = A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$
Displacement relation of a progressive wave is a similar one:
$$y(x,t) = A\cos(kx-\omega t+\phi)$$
Is there a relation between the two? Can the progressive wave relation be derived from the SHM relation? I know that a progressive wave is not the same as the sinusodial wave produced by a rigid body in SHM because I tried to use the same concept to derive the displacement relation for progressive wave but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your shm equation I will write as the displacement $y(t) = A \cos (-\omega t+\Psi)$.
Thus at some position you have a particle executing shm with amplitude $A$, frequency $\omega$, and phase $\Psi$.

Now suppose that the phase $\Psi$ is a function of position $x$.
$\Psi (x) = \psi(x) + \phi\,\Rightarrow \, y(x,t) = A \cos (-\omega t+\Psi(x)) = A \cos (-\omega t +\psi (x) + \phi$).

Nearly there.

Now make the displacement $y(x,t)$ periodic with respect to $x$ by making $\phi(x) = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\,x = kx$ where $\lambda$ is a characteristic length which we call *wavelength* amd $k$ is the *wave number*.

You now have the equation of a wave travelling in the positive $x$ direction,

$y(x,t) = A \cos (kx-\omega t +\phi)$

Answer (score -1):

The first one gives for every $t$ the displacement of the observed body in simple harmonic motion.
[image: SHM]

The second one gives you some quantity in space and time for every $t$ and $x$, let it be the change in pressure (sound), height (string), electric field strenght (light), or something else.
[image: EM wave]

Note, that the two equations represent entirely different phenomena. The first one represents only the position of some discrete object in simple harmonic motion, but the second one is for waves in fields (pressure, height, electric field strength, ...).

On the other hand, the change in some quantity at some point in space is a simple harmonic motion. For this perspective, I advise you to take a look at [Farcher](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/104696/farcher)'s answer to this question.